# How to get data from DB when a string is in another string?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the location fields from my jobs object but when I put `location.address` for example it looks like the syntax is wrong in js.

This are my constants where everything works fine apart of address, city and postcode.

```
const { title, avatar, company, postDate, jobType, payment, duration, description, address, city, postcode } = this.props.navigation.state.params;
```

And here is my DB scheme

```
jobs: [{
      title: {type: String},
      company: {type: String},
      avatar: {type: String},
      created: {type: Boolean},
      applied: {type: Boolean},
      description: {type: String},
      location: [{
          address: {type: String},
          postcode: {type: String},
          city: {type: String}
      }],
      jobType: {type: String},
      payment: {type: String},
      duration: {type: String},
      postDate: {type: Date},
      expDate: {type: Date}
  }]
```

Comment: location is an array, but you are trying to access it as an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

location is an array. Supposedly if location of each data is singleton, that is need not be array. 
Replace

```
...
location: [{
          address: {type: String},
          postcode: {type: String},
          city: {type: String}
      }],
...
```

to

```
...
location: {
          address: {type: String},
          postcode: {type: String},
          city: {type: String}
      },
...
```

and simply use location.address

but it is supposed to be an array, work with it like we work with array

For 1st element

```
location[0].address
```

For 2st element

```
location[1].address
```

For all elements

```
location.forEach(varName){
varName.address
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`location` is a `array` of objects there. You'll have to use some loop to access properties of it like

```
location.forEach(e=>console.log(e.address))
```

This could be your expression

```
const { title, avatar, company, postDate, jobType, payment, duration, description, location } = this.props.navigation.state.params;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't dot on an array.

Your address is nested inside of an array.

```
  location: [{
      address: {type: String},
      postcode: {type: String},
      city: {type: String}
  }]
```

To access it you need to index on it like this

```
jobs[0].location[0].address
```